# android java calling class

Tags: java, android

I had two class put in a java.
The `class` is inside the `public class`.
The problem is how do I call the `class` which is in `public class`.

```
public class MyService extends Service {

    //calling class MainA 
    //This sounds can't work
    MainA a1 = new MainA();


    class MainA extends ActionBarActivity {
        public MainA(){
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think there's no problem in your code :) Did you receive compile error ? If yes, please post that message. :)

Comment: No offense but you need to learn basic Java before tackling Android. What you are asking, from a Java standpoint, is very basic and easy and will be taught in any tutorial. But, it is a different monster from the Android side as far as instantiating the class.